# Qt Creator, Full Screen View

Tags: c++, qt, view, qt-creator

I would like to let the view of my Application to Enlarge when I'm opening it as Full Screen mode, is there any kind of flag/something similar to put in QT Creator?
[image: Standard]

[image: After]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you have designed your application to have a fixed size. If you switch to full-screen the size of your window changes, but your controls keep the same positions and dimensions.

You will have to use layouts, so your application adjusts to size changes. Read  the Documentation on [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) with Qt.

Note that layouts can be applied in code or in design-mode(The bar on top).